# Using dot notation, what is the derivative of $r^2$ with respect to t, when r is a function of t?

Tags: derivatives

I'm a bit confused about using dot notation; I have $A = r^2$, and I need the derivative. Would this be $\frac{dA}{dt}=\dot{r}^2$, $\frac{dA}{dt}=2\dot{r}$, or simply $\frac{dA}{dt}=2r$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $\dfrac{d(r^2)}{dt} =  \dfrac{d(r^2)}{dr} \cdot\dfrac{dr}{dt} = 2r\cdot \dot{r} $

Comment: Oh yes of course, cheers!